# Meromorphic matrix

Tags: matrix-decomposition, meromorphic-functions

I am starting to study some documents for my thesis, maybe this question is basic, but I don´t know precisely what is.

What is a meromorphic matrix?.

Where i can read about of  the precisely definition and/or examples?

could you recommend me some book?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some context might be helpful, but I think the most reasonable assumption is that this refers to a matrix whose entries are meromorphic functions.